# I don't understand why the "this" keyword doesn't work as I expect

Tags: javascript, this

What I want to do is to execute the create_tag function when a specified condition is satisfied. I am referring to this function as a method of an object, in this case document.body, by setting as its method an external function, "create_tag(..)". The problem is inside this function I have a "this" keyword which I would expect to refer to the method's parent, document.body. Instead it doesn't seem to work. I tried replacing "this" with "document.body" in the function so the problem should be caused by "this".
Here is the code:

```
xmlDom=xmlhttp.responseXML;
hint_ul=document.getElementById("hint_ul");
personaggi=xmlDom.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("personaggio");
for(i=0;i<personaggi.length;i++){
    personaggio=personaggi.item(i);
    name=personaggio.childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue;
        if(name.substr(0, str.length).toLowerCase()==str.toLowerCase()){
            document.body.crea_li=create_tag(name);
        }
}
}


function create_tag(inner){
a=document.createElement("a");
a.innerHTML=inner;
this.appendChild(a); }
```

Comment: If you have time, [this](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) is a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`this` will be `window` when called like that.

To get its `this` as the `body` element, call it like so...

```
document.body.crea_li = create_tag.call(document.body, name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a reference to `this` outside the function body - referencing it within the scope later:

```
var self = this;
function create_tag(inner){
    a=document.createElement("a");
    a.innerHTML=inner;
    self.appendChild(a); 
}
```

---

This could be a nice trick. When I make complicated javascript objects involving many objects and functions, at the top of the object I create:

```
var self = this;
```

as that will live within the scope, the root object is always accessible.

Here is a working example of how I would implement this:

```
SomeReallyComplexThing = function() {

    var self = this;
    var foo = 'bar'

    this.fooThing = 'Other thing'

    this.setSomeData = function(){
        console.log('Some data set', arguments)
    }

    this.makeMassiveCall = function() {
        var completeFunc = function(){};
        var url = '/some/endpoint.json';
        var requestData = {};

        jQuery.get(url, requestData, function(data) {

            /*
            * Data has come back
            */
            self.setSomeData(data)
            completeFunc(data);                  
    });

    }

}

//outside the scope
s = new SomeReallyComplexThing()
s.fooThing() //visible
s.self //undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code is `create_tag` assigned as a method of `document.body`. The closest you get is with the line `document.body.crea_li=create_tag(name);`, but what's actually happening here is that you are executing `create_tag` as a member of the global object, and the result of that operation is assigned to `document.body.crea_li`.

Comment: Yes, there's the problem. I guess if it was actually assigned as a method the "this" keyword should have worked as expected. So how could I simply assign it as a method to resolve the problem? Because I tried inserting the function when it is called instead of linking it back to an external function, but that didn't seem to work either..

Answer (score 0):

`this` in javascript is a sqirrely fellow. The idea is `this` refers to the current function context.

This means that when your running code inside the function `this` refers to that function's context, which does not have an `appendChild` method.

Normally you use a closure to keep a reference to the calling context around, something like this

```
var _self = this;

var result = func();

function func()
{
    // _self is the calling context, this is the current context
}
```

Or you could pass a reference to the calling context:

```
document.body.crea_li=create_tag(name,this);



function create_tag(inner, context) { context.body.appendChild(...) }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is referring to the function's parent, but its parent is actually the `window` object, not the `document` object or `document.body`. `this` actually refers to wherever context the function is called from, and in my opinion you should avoid using it to call methods just for that reason because it can be difficult to see what `this` is actually referring to. For example, if you called a function using `this` from another function, it would refer to the context within that function.

This example might help show what's going on:

```
var hello = function() {
    alert( this.message );
}
window.message = "hello!";
hello()
```

You could `document.body` directly in the code like you suggested before, or you could pass another parameter that tells the function where to append the created tag:

```
function create_tag(inner, elementToAddTag){
  a=document.createElement("a");
  a.innerHTML=inner; 
  elementToAddTagTo.appendChild(a); 
}
```